# Unable to get the value from user input inside a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input, return

I think this is pretty straightforward question.
I am calling a function which is asking user input with some error handling as well. The output should be integer (but I think this problem I have in general with all functions asking for any input).
Can you have a look at what I do wrong?
Thanks

```
def askShift():
    while True:
        try:
            cypShift = int(input('Enter number: '))
            return cypShift
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('\n', 'ERROR : Enter a whole number', '\n')

askShift()
print(askShift())
```

Comment: Why do you `break` after the `return`?

Comment: You function should work, but you call `askShift()` twice?

Comment: This function works. Just remove the `break` and the first `askShift()`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks - it was probably the break ... (the first call i added by mistake

Comment: I've checked your code. You don't need the `break` statement after the  `return` stament. Also you call `askShift()` twice. Call it once as you do in the `print` statement.

Comment: @s3icc0: no the `break` is not really a problem: it is however *dead code*: code that cannot be executed because the `return` will prevent that.

Comment: that line you have written `break` never been executed ever , because the in the previous line you have **returned** a *value* :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but since I removed the break it starts returning my value

Comment: @s3icc0: that's because you removed your first call to `askShift()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, but i don't understand ...
the progress was: 
1st - it is not working, add the return
2nd - still not working - probably forgot to call the function
3rd - break removed - working
4th - call removed - ...

Answer (score -1):

So the `break` after `return` has been removed as unreachable code
and the problem was the additional call for the `askShift()` function ...

```
def askShift():
    while True:
        try:
            cypShift = int(input('Enter number: '))
            return cypShift
        except ValueError:
            print('\n', 'ERROR : Enter a whole number', '\n')

print(askShift())
```

Comment: This is not true: if you remove the `break`, the code will still work. It however makes no sense to write a `break`. Did not dv btw.

Comment: this is not true , that break isn't the problem